# Issue while writing data from azure notebook to dedicated sql pool

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-synapse

I'm trying to send data in a dataframe from azure synapse notebook to a already created table in dedicated SQL pool table

```
df.to_sql('dbo.table1', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

conn is using `ODBC driver and py odbc` but I'm getting the following error :

```
 Execution failed on sql:
  SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
  ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
  Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
unable to rollback
```

Comment: Try executing EXEC sp_tables @table_name='table1', @table_owner='dbo' to see the table type and other details

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same in my environment. I got the same error.

[image]

The above error message happens because the Dedicated SQL server trying to access the table, but the table does not exist in the current database. To fix this issue verify that the database and also refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612227/sp-executesql-not-working-from-databricks-pyodc/75623268#75623268) thread for Inserting data from One table to another table.

One of the best approaches to inserting data frames into a Dedicated SQL pool uses JDBC as a connection string.

```
df121.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", jdbc) \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "table1") \
  .option("tempDir", blob) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

For information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775575/error-while-writing-data-from-databricks-to-azure-synapse-dedicated-pool) thread and [MS _Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/jdbc#python-5).